# Replicate a behavior of criteria to criteriaBuilder

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Since `criteria` was deprecated in the latest versions of hibernate I am trying to migrate everything to `criteriaBuilder` in the following way:

```java
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaBuilder
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery

// Create CriteriaBuilder
CriteriaBuilder builder = session.getCriteriaBuilder();

// Create CriteriaQuery
CriteriaQuery<MyClass> criteria = builder.createQuery(MyClass.class);
```

My problem arises when I try to replicate the following behavior:

```java
session.createCriteria(MyClass.class).add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("MyConditions"));
```

So how can I set my conditions via a string using `CriteriaBuilder` / `CriteriaQuery`? (thus replicating the behavior of `Restrictions.sqlRestriction()`).

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible unless you go deep into the guts of Hibernate and create a custom `SQLFunction` that just renders the SQL you pass as string literal into the query. You will have to work with the JPA Criteria API and create proper predicates.

Answer (score -1):

Something like:

```
Root<Item> root = criteria.from(MyClass.class);
criteria.select(root).where(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("MyConditions"));
```

Comment: It throws an error: `java.lang.ClassCastException: class org.hibernate.criterion.SQLCriterion cannot be cast to class javax.persistence.criteria.Expression (org.hibernate.criterion.SQLCriterion and javax.persistence.criteria.Expression are in unnamed module of loader org.apache.catalina.loader.ParallelWebappClassLoader @2f48b3d2)`